# Group by new column without adding it

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to group a dataframe `df` by a series `s` without adding `s` to `df` first?

The reason I am asking is because

```
df.assign(bin=pd.cut(df[what],n)).groupby('bin')
```

seems to create a full copy and that occasionally requires too much memory.

Comment: yes, groupby allows you to group a helper series without assigning it to a dataframe.  please add some data to replicate the question so we can try and comeup with something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with

```
df.groupby(pd.Serise(pd.cut(df[what],n),index=df.index))
```

More info

```
df.groupby(pd.Series(pd.cut(df.c1,3),index=df.index)).sum()
Out[156]: 
              c1  c2  c3
c1                      
(0.994, 3.0]   6  13  13
(3.0, 5.0]     0   0   0
(5.0, 7.0]    13  10   7


df
Out[154]: 
   c1  c2  c3
0   7   5   2
1   1   2   2
2   3   4   3
3   1   4   6
4   1   3   2
5   6   5   5
```